# Recycler add listener onScrollStateChanged that callback scroll state "SCROLL_STATE_IDLE" for a delay time which can't be ignored

Tags: java, android

1. **xml code like this:**

   [image]
2. **page listener code as below:**

   ```
      RecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
       @Override
       public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
           super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
           Log.d("-------newState------->" + newState);
       }
   });
   ```

**when i slipping to move to the top,print log :**

> [onScrollStateChanged() line:412] -------newState------->1
>
> [onScrollStateChanged() line:412] -------newState------->2
>
> [onScrollStateChanged() line:412] -------newState------->0

however after a few seconds the last line log only show.  this is the first question. second question: the com.xxx.ExpadnTabLayout between CollapsingToolbarLayout and AppBarLayout  has click event ,there'll be a popwindow show below it's bottom when i click ExpandTabLayout view. therefore the above cases cause insanity views when the value of "newState"  parameter is 2 .though the page is static and the value isn't change to 0 in a timely manner.so what can  i do for these questions.

**Any help will be appreciated!!!**

Comment: the code above is not complete ,lacking of some CoordinatorLayout and AppBarLayout labels

Comment: The solution just override the method of "onNestedPreScroll" in the HeaderBehavior class ,and stop "mScroller" in it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution just override the method of "onNestedPreScroll" in the HeaderBehavior class ,and stop "mScroller" in it .code below:（**Welcome to point out mistakes >_>**）

```
  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_behavior="com.xxx.android.ui.widgets.behavior.CustomBehavior"
        app:elevation="0dip">
```

***the CustomeBehavior.class:***

```
  private void getParentScroller(Context context) {
    if (mScroller != null) return;
    mScroller = new OverScroller(context);
    try {
        Class<?> reflex_class = getClass().getSuperclass().getSuperclass();
        Field fieldScroller = reflex_class.getDeclaredField("mScroller");
        fieldScroller.setAccessible(true);
        fieldScroller.set(this, mScroller);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
  }

@Override
public void onNestedPreScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, AppBarLayout child, View target, int dx, int dy, int[] consumed, int type) {
    if (mScroller != null) {
        if (mScroller.computeScrollOffset()) {
            mScroller.abortAnimation();
        }
    }
    if (type == ViewCompat.TYPE_NON_TOUCH && getTopAndBottomOffset() == 0) {
        ViewCompat.stopNestedScroll(target, type);
    }
    super.onNestedPreScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dx, dy, consumed, type);
}
```